# android save user preferences permanently?

Tags: android

I am developing a game. I want the user of game to determine the opponents usernames. How can I store these names internally?? I want to store them permanently. Not until the end of the run of application.

Answer (score 6):

There are several methods. Take a look at the developer guide topic [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). Your options include:

1. Shared preferences
2. Internal storage
3. External storage (e.g., sd card)
4. SQLite data base
5. A network connection to a server

Answer (score 2):

You can check the Android Dev site, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html has some good solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use [`Preferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html)

Here is a good tutorial to get you started: http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences