# Android: Permanently saving name

Tags: android, android-intent, eclipse-adt

I have a login page which requires user to enter their name. On the next page, I'm trying to show "Hi, (name)". How can I do that? And can I store this permanently like, when the user restarts the app, it does not require them to key in their name anymore?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android save user preferences permanently?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920151/android-save-user-preferences-permanently)

Comment: but how do i implement it? im confused

Comment: and i dont think user's name is a preferences

Comment: I disagree, it's what they PREFER to be known as

Comment: so i can use saveAsPreference in OnStop() and retrievePreference in OnStart()?

Comment: Sure, or save it when you get it and retrieve it when you need it

Comment: alright, thanks.. how do i unflag a comment? i accidentally clicked on it, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharedPreference, like they said.

example :

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("uName", txtUname.getText());
editor.commit();
```

When required, you can use 'getString("uName")' in place of putString() to read the value.

A stack-overflow link that might help you in-case of any confusions.

[Android - Storing/retrieving strings with shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074156/android-storing-retrieving-strings-with-shared-preferences)

Comment: alright thanks! will try it out

Comment: do i still need the login.xml to be a launcher since it's permanent?

Comment: It really doesn't depend on who is launcher. You can save it anywhere and use it anywhere you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the name from the text view:

```
String name = mTextview.getText();
```

When you launch the next activity you can say:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("NAME", name);
startActivity(intent);
```

In next Activity you can get it using:

```
Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
String name = extra.getStringExtra("NAME");
```

Another approach, if you want to store it permanently, you can use SharedPreferences.

Comment: If it solves your problem sign it as response :D it really helps. Thx

Comment: so, this isn't permanent?